# Create new properties when updating a layer

Tags: wfs, wfs-t, gis-principle

I'm trying to update a property that doesn't exist in my current database, and I want that if it doesn't exist - then create it with my value and only for this specific layer.
For example - I have a database of the states with their names and population, and I want to add whether this state voted republican, democratic or independent, so my request would look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<wfs:Transaction
   version="2.0.0"
   service="WFS"
   xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0
                       http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0.0/wfs.xsd">
   <wfs:Update typeName="topp:states">
      <wfs:Property>
         <wfs:ValueReference>VotedFor</wfs:ValueReference>
         <wfs:Value>democratic</wfs:Value>
      </wfs:Property>
      <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
         <ogc:Literal>Colorado</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Filter>
   </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

And since I don't have in my database the "VotedFor" parameter, I wonder if there is any way to create it "on the fly"

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way with in the [WFS standards](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) to do this. WFS assumes that you have a fixed (and unchangeable) schema (the result of `describeFeature` requests) underlying your features.

Comment: And is there any other standard that is a bit more flexible and that allows that?